# How to retain escape characters after UNCOMPRESS in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, compression, escaping

When I uncompress a compressed string that contains an escaped double quote charater, the resultant string does not contain the escape character ( \ ) itself. This is causing havoc with the subsequent call to `JSONConvert.DeserializeObject`

For example, if I call:

```
SELECT UNCOMPRESS(COMPRESS("Test\"Me"));
```

the expected result is

```
"Test\"Me"
```

but the actual result is

```
"Test"Me"
```

What should I do to get the result I want?

Comment: What makes you say that `"Test\"Me"` is the expected result?

Comment: The backslash is just to enable you to provide a string with a double quote inside. If you print the string `"Test\"Me"`, you will get `Test"Me` as the output.

Comment: @SalmanA simply because that's what I passed in?

Comment: You need to learn the basics of strings, for both languages (SQL and JSON). If you want to "write" the string `test"me` in sql you'd write it as `"test\"me"`. If you want to convert the same string to JSON you don't store backslashes in database, you retrieve the string from db then use a library or function to convert that string to JSON.

Comment: You did _not_ pass the bytes `Test\"Me` to compress. You passed the bytes `Test"Me` to compress.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get `\"` in the middle then you have to escape it twice in the `COMPRESS()` part. Something like this:

```
SELECT UNCOMPRESS(COMPRESS("Test\\\"Me"));
```

Or maybe, instead of wrapping the value in double-quotes, use single quote and do escaping once only on the backslash, something like this:

```
SELECT UNCOMPRESS(COMPRESS('Test\\"Me'));
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fdd03e3af94bf358d4040b363074f36e)